Why do I need a USB-C controller for PD?
I am trying to design the SOURCE part. If I want to be able to supply 5V at 3A to a load using USB-C PD then I assume all I have to do is the following:

This is according to the latest USB-C standard for PD.
Why do I need a USB-C controller if this will work?
This is just a simplified drawing, but it should work. Can someone with more experience assist in determining if this will work?
Why should I go with a USB-C PD IC instead of this?
I am just confused why we need a USB-C controller if I know what voltage and current I require.

Compliant USB devices with USB-C connectors are required to not provide 5V on VBUS until they actually see another device on the other end that is requesting that they do so for a long list of safety reasons. It’s possible to handle this entirely yourself (though your proposed circuit does not do this), but a dedicated PD controller will handle it for you, as well as ensuring negotiation works correctly and possibly shortening your overall BOM.

For those EE members who don't have depth in USB technology but would still like to follow the question and answers as much as possible: PD == Power Delivery

You don't need a PD controller for 5 V 3 A, as long as you advertise 3 A being available with the correct resistor.
However, simply connecting 5 V to receptacle is dangerous and forbidden by USB specs: you are not allowed to do that because if you accidentally connect two power sources together they will damage.
Your device must keep the 5 V at the receptacle VBUS turned off until you reliably detect that a device requesting 5 V with the 5.1 kΩ resistor is present. Only then you are allowed to turn on the 5 V at the receptacle.
Implementing that feature might simply be referred as the PD controller.
The trick is, the device needs to detect from source resistors how much current is available, and it can't pull more than advertised. As an example, you might have a 5 V 3 A supply with two ports, and it will have CC pins wired so that plugging one load with 5.1 kΩ resistors makes it signal 3 A and plugging another load with 5.1 kΩ resistor makes it signal 1.5 A to both loads.
Of course if you want to live dangerously and be non-compliant with USB standard and possibly damage things by simply plugging them together, you can do anything you want, but then why even bother using the CC lines at all, or even using Type-C connectors for custom purposes?

To add more information to this answer, implementing this is important for dealing with legacy cables, such as USB A plug to USb C plug. If a desktop computer is turned of, then connected using one of such cables to an USB C charger, it should not receive any power, as backfeeding power over USB has resulted in hard bricked computers before

@Ferrybig That's a little bad wording. While you should not plug a cable with Type-A plug and Type-C plug, it must not make any difference if the computer is turned on or off, it must not damage. Which is why the charger must detect it is not connected to a device requesting power but to another host and why it must not provide power out unless a device that identifies it needs power is plugged.

Technically your design is in right direction, except that the VBUS should be turned ON only when your power source detects the connection. To accomplish this, you need to have voltage sensors (comparators) on CC lines, and have a high-side power switch to control VBUS out. Having +5V on VBUS on Type-C receptacle without connected sink is prohibited by specifications.
If no device is connected, the CC lines will read +5V. When any device is connected, one of CC wires will go down in proportion of 10k : 5.1k, or down to about 1.7V. Once you see that voltage change, you should turn +5V VBUS on. I guess the schematic to accomplish this function can be called a "simple PD controller".
